# Adding a period to an option value and using with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to disable certain item combinations in a set of drop downs (select boxes). I have this code that works pretty well, however I am trying to combine it with a combination filter for isotope that is using periods in the values ie: value=".filter-apple" Adding periods to this script stops it from working.

I tried to escape the period in the script using "\" with no effect and also by placing it into a [".filter-apple"] which seemed to stop syntax errors, but still doesn't work.

The value needs to go into 4 places to work:
  1. the option value of the item.
  2. the class of the item you're hiding.
  and two places in the script.

The script works fine as long as the values don't have periods. Is there a different way to do this? I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work with the period or if there is a way to add a second value without the period. I tried value="Color,.filter-color"

```js
$('select[name*="select"]').change(function() {
  var selectedOptions = $(this).find('option:selected');
  $('select option').removeAttr('disabled');
  selectedOptions.each(function() {        
    var value = this.value;
    console.log(value);
    if (value !== ''){           
      var id = $(this).parent('select[name*="select"]').attr('id');
      var options = $('select:not(#' + id + ') option[value=' + value + ']');
      if (value == "Apple") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Apple'));
      }
      if (value == "Pear") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Pear'));
      }
      if (value == "Strawberry") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Strawberry'));
      }
      //Sizes
      if (value == "Small") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Small'));
      }
      if (value == "Medium") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Medium'));
      }
      if (value == "Large") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Large'));
      }
      // Colors
      if (value == "Red") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Red'));
      }
      if (value == "Green") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Green'));
      }
      if (value == "Yellow") {
       options = $.merge(options,$('select:not(#' + id + ') option.Yellow'));
      }
      console.dir(options);
      options.attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
    
  });
}); 

$(function () {
        $("#btnReset").bind("click", function () {
            $("#select-type")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            $("#select-size")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            $("#select-color")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
      <select name="select-type" id="select-type">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option class="Small Medium Red Yellow" value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option class="Small Large Red Green" value="Pear">Pear</option>
        <option class="Medium Large Green Yellow" value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>  
      </select>
</div>

<div class="">
      <select name="select-size" id="select-size">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option class="Apple Pear Green Yellow" value="Small">Small</option>
        <option class="Apple Strawberry Red Green" value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option class="Pear Strawberry Red Yellow" value="Large">Large</option>  
      </select>
</div>

<div class="">
      <select name="select-color" id="select-color">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option class="Apple Pear Medium Large" value="Red">Red</option>
        <option class="Pear Strawberry Small Medium" value="Green">Green</option>
        <option class="Apple Strawberry Small Large" value="Yellow">Yellow</option>   
      </select>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is far too repetitive and a bit overly complex and can be greatly simplified to something like:

```
$(function() {
  // store reference to all <select> to be used in various places
  var $selects = $('select[name*="select"]');

  $selects.change(function(e) {
    // get value of current `<select>` that was changed
    var selectedVal = this.value;

    // "this" is the current `<select>`
    // use not() to filter out current `<select>`
    // use `hasClass()` instead of manually concatenating class selector
    $selects.not(this).find('option').prop('disabled', function() {
      // will be false if this option value or class doesn't match selected value
      // otherwise if one condition true it will get disabled
      return this.value === selectedVal || $(this).hasClass(selectedVal )
    });    
  });

  $("#btnReset").bind("click", function() {
     // set empty value on all `<select>` and enable all options
    $selects.val('').find('option').prop('disabled', false)
  });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0doz6pzk/)**</kbd>

Note that a non-multiple `<select>`  value is the same as the selected option value and you can use [`prop(propName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) as well as [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to target  and enable/disable the other `<select>` options with just a couple of lines of code.

You can use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) instead of manually creating the class selector also

Comment: That's great thank you for streamlining the code, everything seems to be working now. Just one small thing I wanted to ask about it. In your solution, sometimes when you select a few options the "All" option gets disabled on some of the select boxes, I'm not sure if that's supposed to be happening. It looks like when you select an option for each drop down, only one can go back to "All" and the others are disabled.

Comment: Try changing to `return (selectedVal && this.value === selectedVal) || $(this).hasClass(selectedVal )`

Comment: I changed the line: `return this.value === val || $(this).hasClass(val)` to `return (selectedVal && this.value === selectedVal) || $(this).hasClass(selectedVal )` as you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work at all. @charlietfl

Comment: OK. This works `$selects.not(this).find('option').filter(function(){return this.value}).prop('disabled', function() {
      return  this.value === selectedVal  || $(this).hasClass(selectedVal )
    })`  https://jsfiddle.net/0doz6pzk/2/